# "socket error: EOF" using python imaplib. Appeared after a week of code working correctly

Tags: python, imaplib

This is my code

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
mail.login(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
mail.select('inbox')
```

I have it looping through every 5 seconds to check for new messages and do something with it. After a week of this working 100%, I suddenly started getting the error "command: SELECT => socket error: EOF"

There was also a very long delay before this appeared- it wasn't immediate- making me think it is a timeout error.

Anyway, 12 hours later and the code is working again fine. But I'm scared it'll happen again.

What caused the issue, and how do I prevent it from happening again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this happens with Gmail (and probably other providers) after a certain number of queries, you just need to login again when this happens. Be careful if you're using IDs that aren't UIDs because they could change on restart.

```py
def login(mailbox):
    print('Logging in again')
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
    mail.login(USERNAME,PASSWORD)
    mail.select(mailbox)
    return mail

mailbox='inbox'

try:
  mail.select()
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
  mail = login(mailbox)
```

You should also do the same exception handling for any fetch method you're using because sometimes it fails there as well.